# How do I get Ansible to use the same SSH port as the SSH proxy packer has launched?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, packer, winrm

I'm running packer inside a docker container to provision a windows server in AWS. I'm using winrm to connect to the packer builder but I run into a problem when running an ansible playbook step in my packer build.

It seems that packer launches an ssh proxy which then forwards the commands to my remote machine via winrm (from the logs):

```
packer: 2017/11/09 09:33:37 SSH proxy: serving on 127.0.0.1:45145
```

A little further down, I see this:

```
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root[0m
 <127.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto
-o ControlPersist=60s 
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 
-o 'IdentityFile="/tmp/ansible-key835953388"' 
-o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no 
-o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey 
-o PasswordAuthentication=no 
-o User=root 
-o ConnectTimeout=10 
-o ControlPath=/root/.ansible/cp/842df7d42c 127.0.0.1 'PowerShell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -EncodedCommand <redacted>'
<127.0.0.1> (255, '', 'ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused\r\n')
```

I see an obvious problem:

"SSH proxy: serving on 127.0.0.1:**45145**" ---> "ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port **22**"

Packer uses a 'random' port each time - and ansible is using the default port.

**How can I get packer to use the same port as ansible?**

Comment: Could you explain why you would like that?

Comment: Because I need ansible to be able to connect to the SSH proxy that packer has launched - at the moment it cannot as it is using a different port.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions here https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html#winrm-communicator and did you specify `communicator: winrm` in your template. It's really hard to understand your problem if you don't supply your `template.json` or explains really carefully each detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I just needed to supply a config setting to packer:

https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/ansible.html#local_port

> local_port (string) - The port on which to attempt to listen for SSH connections. This value is a starting point. The provisioner will attempt listen for SSH connections on the first available of ten ports, starting at local_port. A system-chosen port is used when local_port is missing or empty.